# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data, map plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a world map with points that represents terrorist attacks using ggplot2. The higher is the number of killed person, the bigger is the point. I took the dataset from https://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/. I'm getting the error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data" but i don't why. Thank you

```
dat <- data.frame(latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude, nkill = nkill)

p <- ggplot()
world <- map_data("world")
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = group), colour = "white", fill = "gray")
p <- p + coord_map(xlim = range(longitude), ylim = range(latitude))
p <- p + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size = nkill, color = nkill))
```

Data have the following structure

```
   latitude longitude nkill
1  8.868790 -73.19409     0
2  2.059819  45.32612     4
3 30.200819  66.99435     3
4 29.034412  69.15866     0
5 36.354145  43.14357     2
6 33.994591  44.35727     2
```

Comment: Hi Gianmarco, can you provide the data (or a subset of exactly what you are working with) using `dput` so that this is a minimum reproducible example? Clicked over to the web site & was not immediately evident how you imported latitude, longitude, and nkill. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, I did it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this helps :

```
ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(
    data=world, 
    aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
    colour="white",
    fill="gray") + 
coord_quickmap(
    xlim=range(dat$longitude),
    ylim=range(dat$latitude)) + 
geom_point(
    data=dat,
    aes(
        x=longitude,
        y=latitude,
        size=nkill,
        colour=nkill)) + 
theme_void()
```